# ESXi Free Edition Physical CPU Usage

Tags: vmware-esxi

I understand that in the free edition of ESXi we can only allocate 8 virtual cores to the guest VM.

In my lab I have a PC with 16 Cores. Will ESXi use all 16 cores (which I believe it should) OR will it only use 8 cores?

Any documentation link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It will use all 16 physical cores, but you will not be able to use VMs that have more than 8 virtual cores.

When you power up a VM with, for example 12 cores, you will get the error message:

> Feature 'Virtual SMP' not licensed, requires 12 have 8

[image]

The host I used to test this has four VMs running, totaling 13 vCPUs.